# Reparametrization and Path integrals

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let c(t)=(cost,sint) for 0≤t≤2π and let p(t)=(cost,sint) for 0≤t≤4π. Is it true that ∫c ​ F⋅ds=∫p ​ F⋅ds for every continuous vector field F on {R}^2?
*∫c ​ F⋅ds=∫p ​ F⋅ds are both path integrals.

Choices are:

a. True for all vector fields F

b. True for some vector fields F and false for others

c. False for all vector fields F

d. It's complicated

Intuitively, I thought a is correct as the endpoints of both parametrization matches, but it seems to be not the case (as indicated by my homework grading). Right answer seem to be b, but I have zero idea why.
Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the endpoints hold, the path $c(t)$ corresponds to going around the unit circle one time, while $p(t)$ corresponds to going around the unit circle twice. As such, we expect the line integrals (the term path integral is usually reserved for a more complicated type of integral) along $c(t)$ and $p(t)$ to be different.

However, there are examples of vector fields where the line integrals are the same. Try to come up with one yourself if you haven't!

Comment: Thank you very much! Would $F(x,y)=(-2,2)$ work in this case?

Comment: Yup! Actually, any constant vector field would work, as you may check. For an example of a non-constant vector field, see $F(t) = (-\sin(t), \cos(t))$.

Comment: Oops! I meant $F(t) = (\cos(t),\sin(t))$, not $(-\sin(t),\cos(t))$.  $(-\sin(t),\cos(t))$ is the direction of $ds$, so that wouldn't work of course. My bad.